# What is meant by Thoreau in "A church that can never have done with excommunicating Christ while it exists!"?

Tags: meaning, henry-david-thoreau, a-plea-for-captain-john-brown

In [A Plea for Captain John Brown](https://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/2567/pg2567-images.html), Thoreau writes:

> **A church that can never have done with excommunicating Christ while it exists!** Away with your broad and flat churches, and your narrow and tall churches! Take a step forward, and invent a new style of out-houses. Invent a salt that will save you, and defend our nostrils.

[I have done some research](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_done_with), yet it remains unclear to me what is the author trying to say in this sentence. Is claiming to be both a Christian and a supporter of slavery compared here to a church that tries to excommunicate the Christ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is claiming to be both a Christian and a supporter of slavery compared here to a church that tries to excommunicate the Christ?

In a word: yes.

To elaborate: Thoreau saw slavery as a great sin, "contrary to the law of God"<sup>1</sup> and to all of Jesus's teachings about loving one's neighbor as oneself, proclaiming liberty to captives<sup>2</sup>, etc. Here, he is criticizing the churches and churchgoers of his day who have failed to speak out or take action against the sin of slavery, yet still think of themselves as "Christian" because they follow the customary outward forms of the religion. This is contrasted with John Brown's own sincere Christian faith and devotion, which motivated him to take brave and decisive action against injustice.

A later paragraph similarly equates acceptance of slavery with false Christianity and opposition to Christ:

> What shall we think of a government to which all the truly brave and just men in the land are enemies, standing between it and those whom it oppresses? A government that pretends to be Christian and crucifies a million Christs every day!

The "million Christs" are the slaves, who suffer each day because the government upholds the institution of slavery.

Further along, Thoreau again holds up Brown's sincere Christianity—indeed, his Christlikeness—as a rebuke to hollower forms of the religion:

> You who pretend to care for Christ crucified, consider what you are about to do to him [i.e. Brown] who offered himself to be the savior of four millions of men.

---

<sup>1</sup> Quote from Thoreau's lecture "Slavery in Massachusetts", 1854.

<sup>2</sup> Technically the prophet Isaiah proclaimed it first, but that's beside the point.